# Moving magento site from one server to another server

Tags: magento

i have a magento site version `1.4.1.1.`

And i upgraded the site to `1.7.0.2.`

Now want to  move the upgraded magento into another server .

How can i do this?

```
i planed to do this by downloading all files and upload it into new server.and import the database into the same databsae name.
```

If there is any problem occur when i following the above steps.

Or if there is any rules to move magento site from one server to another server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your sites are not publick then just move the files and db and fix base_urls on db.

If your site is live then here's a thing or two to note down on moving sites:

CODE:

this is straightforward, static assets can be moved beforehand to new server

- easy enough to perform with rsync or version control or even with plain old ftp
- verify file-structure and permissions

DATABASE:

this is more complicated as you have to avoid the gap of getting more orders on old server database after you have switched to move your site database you need to take our site down for the time you move your database

- first step move the database to new server for testing , test if everything works
- make a not of all queries you need to run to make it work on new server (base urls etc)
- repeat this process when you take down the site and open the other

THE PROCESS ON CODE AND DATABASE:

- add a maintenance page on your old page with proper http header
- while site is down move the database to new server
- open up your new site and do a short run on verifying if all works
- next step is to change the domains to point to a new server

MOVING THE DOMAINS

again moving domains is a bit tricky thing as there is a possible DNS blackout that some clients will see the old site and some are seeing the new.

- change your domain rules to point to a new server
- clients who's DNS is not changed jet will see the maintenance page
- clients who have the new DNS already will end up on moved sites

this way you can ensure that you will not get orders on both sites. If your domain-changes completely then you also need to remap your URLS to new domains for every search engine