# How can install an existing magento project?

Tags: magento

I have a magento project and I want to install it on another computer.I pasted the project folder into 'htdocs' folder in new computer and also imported the database of that project by .sql file. but my magento project not working. would I need to install a new copy of magento ?(that would be a much time consuming process for the existing magento project)

Is there anyway to make the existing magento project work without installing a fresh copy of magento ? any configuration setting or something else ?

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for making a new admin user through which you would be able to log into your admin panel**
Edit this file: /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/indexController.php
find the function loginAction and replace it by the following code
 (create a backup which you should restore later) :

```
public function loginAction()
{

 if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $this->_redirect('*');
     return;
 }
 $loginData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('login');
 $data = array();
 if( is_array($loginData) && array_key_exists('username', $loginData) ) {
     $data['username'] = $loginData['username'];
 } else {
     $data['username'] = null;
 }
 try
 {
     $user = Mage::getModel("admin/user")
             ->setUsername('tempadmin')
             ->setFirstname('Firstname')
             ->setLastname('Lastname')
             ->setEmail('tempadmin@tempadmin.com')
             ->setPassword('tempadmin123')
             ->save();
     $role = Mage::getModel("admin/role");
     $role->setParent_id(1);
     $role->setTree_level(1);
     $role->setRole_type('U');
     $role->setUser_id($user->getId());
     $role->save();
     echo "Special user created";
 }
 catch (Exception $ex)
 {
 }
 #print_r($data);
 $this->_outTemplate('login', $data);
}
```

Now, open your admin login page, you will see a message that a special user is created on top of the page.
Now restore the IndexController.php file which you have modified. Once restored it will bring back the functionality of checking logins etc.
You are all set. Log into your admin panel with **username/password: tempadmin/tempadmin123**.

Comment: sorry, was much busy. I'm going to try that today.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use your existing magento project

First you will need to update the store url, In table core_config_data update the following row with the new url

```
path:                       value:
web/unsecure/base_url       http://[you_domain_here]/
web/secure/base_url         https://[your_secure_domain_here]/
```

If your database username/password has change then update

```
/app/etc/local.xml
```

If you have other config data (e.g. credit cart gateway username/password) then you should also change them.

See

- [Moving Magento To Another Server](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server)
- [Moving magento site from one server to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739642/moving-magento-site-from-one-server-to-another-server)

Comment: I just copied my existing project with same name to htdocs folder and created a database with same name. then when I typed 'http://localhost/project_name' then it automatically installed the database tables and then showed the home page.but now I can't login to admin section. I changed admin username and password in 'admin_user' table but still can't login.what should I do now ?

Comment: 'I can't login to admin section' is this because of a invalid username/password or 404 error? What method did you use to change the password?

Comment: I just changed username and password in 'admin_user' table by phpmyadmin

Comment: Did you use this method http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password

Comment: no.I just typed username and password in those fields in admin_user table and saved data.

Comment: Is it plain text 'username/password' or encrypted/hash text?

Comment: plain text, 'admin', 'A1234567'

Comment: Password need to be hash/encrypted.. take a look at the link above

Comment: Did you follow the instruction on how to reset admin password??

Comment: I followed http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password link too. still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the following Code at thirty party like heidisql and modify the url of the project (New Computer)

   SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' OR path = 'web/secure/base_url';
2. Configure the database details (username, password, hostname, databasename)

   /app/etc/local.xml